# Validate Apple receipts: HTTP status code for illegal receipts

Tags: ios, http, in-app-purchase, verification

So I was verifying auto-renewable subscription receipts when I ran into this problem:

Somebody wanted to subscribe to my app with the famous

> "product_id":"com.zeptolab.ctrbonus.superpower1"

hack. Of course, I do not allow this ;) but I would like to know which HTTP status (REST Web Service) should I return to my client app to let it know what happened here.

Should I return a 403 Forbidden? Is there a specific status for this situation?

I have been tempted to return a "418 I'm a teapot" but I decided to ask you guys first.

Comment: Send back a 200 with a response to load a locked screen that says "Pirates not allowed"